# Understanding the Framework of Automation with Ruby and Cucumber

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, capybara

Can someone explain or send me some material so I can understand the meaning of each directory in this structure?

```
specs            =   I understand
step_definitions =   I understand
support\env      =   I have doubts
cucumber.yml     =   I have doubts
Rakefile         =   I have doubts
Helper.rb        =   I have doubts
```

Comment: Regretfully, your question is not suitable for SO because it is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I have voted to close.

Comment: I often resist efforts to close questions, but this one is clearly out-of-bounds. At the link in my previous comment: "3. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...".

Comment: Many times some users tell us to study or even look for readings, including sending support links .. But OK, thanks